# Checking for real positive integers

Tags: matlab

How can I improve (shorten) my check that values are real positive integer? I want to do it first for just an integer (a), for which I have tried

```
 a~=floor(a) || a<=0 || imag(a)~=0
```

Secondly, I'd like to do it for a linked list

```
l=struct('xpos',value,'ypos',value,'entry',value,'next',[])
l=struct('xpos',value,'ypos',value,'entry',value,'next',l)
```

and so on.

For the list I want all xpos and ypos values to be real positive integers, I have tried

```
 any(l.xpos~=floor(a) || l.xpos<=0 || imag(l.xpos)~=0 || l.ypos~=floor(l.ypos) || l.ypos<=0 || imag(l.ypos)~=0)
```

This ends up being quite long when I had two lists to check.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly simplify your check and turn it into an anonymous function using something like:

```
isPositiveInt = @(x)isscalar(x) && isnumeric(x) && abs(round(x)) == x && x > 0;
```

If it's guaranteed that it will always be a scalar and numeric you can simplify this to:

```
isPositiveInt = @(x)abs(round(x)) == x && x > 0;
```

Then you could easily perform this check for both `xpos` and `ypos`

```
isPositiveInt(S.xpos) && isPositiveInt(S.ypos)
```

To go through your "linked list" you'll just need to loop through it

```
while ~isempty(S)
    % They they are both integers do something
    if isPositiveInt(S.xpos) && isPositiveInt(S.ypos)
        % Do something
    end

    % Go onto the next one
    S = S.next;
end
```

As a side-note, it's best to avoid using a lower-case `l` as a variable since it looks a lot like the number `1`. I have switched it out for `S` in the example above.

Comment: What about checking whether it's real or a complex number? I also don't see the need for isscalar.

Comment: @CarlyCoop That's handled by `abs`

Comment: Would imag not work better? And, how do I implement the while loop as a condition for an if-statement?

Comment: @CarlyCoop No. `abs(round(` accomplishes the check for real and integers at the same time. I don't know what you mean by your second statement

Comment: So I have an if statement for which the condition is that x.pos and y.pos have only real positive integers.

Comment: Thank you! Finally, could you explain the purpose of isscalar?

Comment: @CarlyCoop How is that confusing? It checks whether it is a scalar like the name implies.

Comment: I get that, but why is it included? I'm only checking values, not arrays.

Comment: @CarlyCoop If you are guaranteed that they are never going to be empty or never be an array then you can remove that piece. Updated with an example.